# Создание хранилища объектов

Tags: c#, память

Товарищи, встал перед такой проблемой:

Мне необходимо реализовать нечто вроде хранилища объектов, которое бы выдавало по одному экземпляру указанного объекта на *пользователя*

Попробую пояснить с помощью псевдокода:

```
// Добавим в хранилище правило создания объекта 
storage.Add("tmp", () => new Foo()); 

{
    // В хранилище пока нет сгенерированных объектов
    // Так что создаётся новый, сохраняется и возвращается 
    Foo tmp0 = storage["tmp"];
}

// Здесь ссылка на tmp0 уже недействительна 
// Так что единственная ссылка на тот созданный объект лежит внутри хранилища 
// Возвращаем тот же объект, что был в tmp0
Foo tmp1 = storage["tmp"];

// Тот объект, что был создан для tmp0, а теперь хранится в tmp1, уже занят 
// Так что создаём новый объект, сохраняем его в хранилище и его же и возвращаем 
Foo tmp2 = storage["tmp"];
```

То есть при завершении области видимости для `tmp0` хранилище, содержащее в себе ссылку на тот же объект, его не удаляет, а сохраняет до следующего запроса подобного объекта.

То есть логика такая:

1. Идёт запрос объекта по ключу
2. Если в хранилище нет уже созданных объектов - сгенерировать его по заданному правилу, сохранить и после этого вернуть . Иначе:
3. Проверить для каждого созданного объекта, есть ли на него ссылка в пользовательском коде. Если нет (то есть единственная ссылка лежит в самом хранилище) - вернуть найдённый объект

Такое поведение нужно мне по следующей причине: создание `Foo` - трудоёмкий процесс. Помимо этого `Foo` не является потокобезопасным, так что на руках у каждого пользователя `Foo` должен быть свой уникальный экземпляр, который, возможно, уже был создан и использован ранее.

Вроде как нигде нет *«счётчика»* ссылок на объекты, так как сборщику мусора плевать, сколько там раз была объявлена ссылка на определённый объект. Важно лишь то, есть ли таковая ссылка вообще

Так что даже не знаю, возможно ли вообще реализовать подобное средствами `C#`...

---

**UPD:**

Я никак не могу выбрать, какой ответ пометить галочкой, ибо ответы от [iluxa1810](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/902867/248572) и [default locale](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/902878/248572)  являются более правильными для общего случая. Однако в рамках моей весьма специфичной задачи более подходит метод, описанный в ответе от [John](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/902946/248572)...

Comment: Есть, конечно, идея описать обертку для хранимого типа с кастомным финализатором, вызов которого и будет оповещать меня о том, что объект более не используется. Но это видится мне немного неправильным

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что Вы хотите чтобы при завершении области видимости переменной `tmp0` она «освобождала» объект в `storage` на который она ссылается? Можете пояснить для чего нужно такое поведение?

Comment: @defaultlocale: дополнил вопрос

Comment: Помечайте галочкой тот вариант, который больше всего подходит именно вам, отсутствие галочки не делает другие ответы плохими или неправильными. К тому же ответы могут устаревать со временем и терять актуальность, поэтому галочка здесь просто как еще один способ отблагодарить отвечающего. За остальное не беспокойтесь — сообщество отметит другие ответы голосами со временем.

Comment: @АндрейNOP: да я понимаю, я как раз и мечусь от того, что каждый из ответов по-своему правильный ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ Жаль, что на SE нет каких-нибудь *вторичных* галочек, чтобы из множества ответов также помечать те, которые по сути правильны, пусть ты и выбрал иной

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно вывернуться, создав класс-обертку.

Я постараюсь вкратце сейчас, потому что с телефона.

Суть в том, что мы используем финализатор обертки, чтобы отловить событие удаления обертки и вернуть наш экземпляр в строй.

Создаём наш класс-обертку:

```
class FooWrapper
{
   public event Action<int> Final;

   private Foo foo;
   private int id;

   public FooWrapper(Foo foo, int id)
   {
      this.foo = foo;
      this.id = id;
   }

   // Вот и наш финализатор
   ~FooWrapper()
   {
       if (Final != null)
           Final(id)
   }
}
```

В самой программе создаём два словаря. Один - для неиспользуемых экземпляров foo, а второй - для используемых.

Думаю, логика более или менее понятна?

1) по требованию пользователя ищется в словарях экземпляр Foo. В данном случае по Id.

2) если нет, то создаётся Foo и помещается во второй словарь. Его мы передаём в FooWrapper и обязательно подписываемся на событие Final. Полученный FooWrapper уже отдаем пользователю.

3) после того, как у пользователя пропадают все ссылки на FooWrapper срабатывает финализатор, в котором срабатывает событие Final, передающее ID нашего Foo.

4) В основной программе мы получаем этот Id и переносим из второго словаря в первый.

Главный недостаток, что в данном случае мы полностью исключает возможность взаимодействия напрямую с foo, только через методы, который в fooWrapper пропишешь.

Comment: Собственно, Вы развернули то, что я описал в комментариях) В итоге, кстати, я и использовал этот метод таким образом: унаследовал обертку от общего с объектом абстрактного класса, описав все методы с помощью сокрытого внутри отслеживаемого объекта. Так как «хранилище» итак возвращало абстракцию, с точки зрения пользователей такая махинация совершенно не заметна (если, конечно, не лезть в рефлексию)

Answer (score 2):

Вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686416/c-sharp-get-number-of-references-to-object) похожий вопрос и там предоставляется решение в виде использования [`WeakReference`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.weakreference?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) -это такая ссылка на объект, которая не препятствует сборки мусора. У него есть свойство `IsAlive`, которое говорит жив ли объект или уже был собран сборщиком мусора.
Мне видится, что это вы можете задействовать в своей задаче. В вашем случае, объект будет жив до тех пор, пока кто-то на него ссылается из кода.

Проверить, есть ли ссылка на объект в коде нельзя. `.NET` ушли от подсчета кол-ва ссылок на объект в пользу построения графа доступности объектов.

Как альтернативный вариант- это ввести внутри вашего хранилища подсчет, заставляя пользователя вызывать спец. метод. Но тут все строится на доверии... Например, вдруг забудут что-либо вызвать => объект будет зарегистрирован за кем-то.

Comment: Таки да, про `WeakReference` знаю, право я узнаю о том, что объект освобождён пользователем лишь тогда, когда он будет собран сборщиком мусора ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯  Это не совсем то, что я хотел сделать. Собственно, в виду отсутствия счетчика ссылок на объект, моя задача для случайного объекта видится невозможной...) Ладно. Подождём до вечера. Вдруг у кого-то появится идея) Если нет - помечу ответом)  Только прошу Вас: напомните, пожалуйста. А то память у меня дырявая)

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, если только обязать каждого пользователя явно что-то дергать, что бы показать свободность объекта, а внутри своего класса реализовать счетчик. Ну это будет работать на доверии...

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, в Net найдется механизм, который решит задачу, в том виде, в каком Вы ее написали. Но, если честно, мне это решение кажется неочевидным и хрупким:

- неочевидным, т.к. конец блока кода легко пропустить при чтении, и, поэтому, редко используется для критичных операций:

  ```
  } //за одним символом здесь кроется важная операция по освобождению объекта.
  ```

  Как разработчик, я ожидаю, что блоки кода можно свободно переставлять при рефакторинге. В данном случае при этом нужно будет очень внимательно отследить срок жизни всех переменных. Ситуация усложнится если ссылки на `Foo` будут сохраняться в полях других классов (объекты которых сами будут храниться в коллекциях и захватываться в лямбдах).
- хрупким, т.к. в данном случае логика будет сильно зависеть от работы сборщика кода, которую сложно контролировать.

### Альтернатива: объектный пул

Для решения Вашей проблемы (дорогостоящие объекты, которые желательно переиспользовать) подойдет шаблон проектирования «[объектный пул](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BB)». Пулы широко используются для схожих задач (хранения соединений к БД, например).

В простейшем варианте Вам достаточно:

- Реализовать для `Foo` интерфейс [`IDisposable`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable).
- В `storage` отслеживать вызов метода `Dispose` для созданных `Foo` и освобождать объекты.
- В вызывающем коде всегда оборачивать полученные из `storage` объекты в блок [`using`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement)
- Для чистоты эксперимента можно вынести методы/свойства `Foo` в отдельный интерфейс, который и возвращать из `storage`. Реализацию `Foo` оставить доступной только для `storage`, чтобы никто не мог переопределить методы.

Решение скучное и предполагает изменение вызывающего кода. Зато в данном варианте процесс освобождения объектов становится очевидным.

Ну и код будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
 using(var tmp0 = fooPool.GetFoo("tmp")) 
 {
      //работаем с одним объектом
 }

 using(var tmp1 = fooPool.GetFoo("tmp")) 
 {
      using(var tmp2 = fooPool.GetFoo("tmp")) 
      {
           //работаем с двумя объектами
      }
 }
```

Comment: Собственно, логика объекта такова, что от перестановки блоков кода местами логика его работы не изменится. Так что *за одним символом кроется важная* лишь для системной части операция, для пользователя же она может оставаться сокрытой, так как в его коде не играет логики) Вот примерно объектный пул я создать и хотел)